# EF Query creates a ton of subqueries

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have the following data structure:

A `Meeting` has 1 to many `MeetingRooms`

A `MeetingRoom` has 1 to many `Meeting`

The are related through a join-table:

```
public class MeetingRoomMeeting : Entity
    {
        public Guid MeetingRoomId { get; set; }
        public virtual MeetingRoom MeetingRoom { get; set; }

        public Guid MeetingId { get; set; }
        public virtual Meeting Meeting { get; set; }
    }
```

A meeting also has attendees, which is defined as:

A `Meeting` has 1 to many `Attendees`

An `Attendee` has 1 `Meeting`

I have two queries:

Get all `meetings` for a `meeting room` and

Get the average `attendees` for all `meetings` in a `meeting room`

The difference in the query execution time is roughly 100-200ms for only getting the meetings for a room, and ~30-50 seconds for getting the attendees.

The queries are as follows:

This returns the list of meetings (for further aggregations and transformation). It is meetings for a specific room (defined by it's Guid) between a set of dates.

```
var meetings = _reader.Query()
               .Where(room => room.Id == query.Id)
               .Include(room => room.Meetings)
                   .ThenInclude(meeting => meeting.Meeting)
               .Select(room => new Models.MeetingRoom
               {
               Id = room.Id,
               Name = room.Name,
               Location    = room.Location,
               Meetings = room.Meetings.Where(meeting => meeting.Meeting.StartTime >= query.StartTime && meeting.Meeting.EndTime <= query.EndTime).Select(meeting => new MeetingRoomMeeting
                   {
                       MeetingId = meeting.MeetingId,
                       Meeting = meeting.Meeting
                   }).ToList()
               })
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

It generates the following query:

```
'SELECT [meeting.Meeting].[Id], [meeting.Meeting].[BookedAt], [meeting.Meeting].[DeliveryId], [meeting.Meeting].[EndTime], [meeting.Meeting].[EndedAt], [meeting.Meeting].[LocationId], [meeting.Meeting].[StartTime], [meeting.Meeting].[Subject], [meeting.Meeting].[UpdatedAt], [meeting.Meeting].[WasAdhoc], [meeting.Meeting].[WasCancelled], [meeting.Meeting].[WasEnded], [meeting.Meeting].[WasNoShow], [meeting].[MeetingRoomId], [meeting].[MeetingId]
FROM [MeetingRoomMeeting] AS [meeting]
INNER JOIN [Meeting] AS [meeting.Meeting] ON [meeting].[MeetingId] = [meeting.Meeting].[Id]
WHERE ([meeting.Meeting].[StartTime] >= @__query_StartTime_1) AND ([meeting.Meeting].[EndTime] <= @__query_EndTime_2)',N'@__query_StartTime_1 datetime2(7),@__query_EndTime_2 datetime2(7)',@__query_StartTime_1='2016-10-02 22:00:00',@__query_EndTime_2='2016-11-03 22:59:59'
```

Now the culprit query which is identical, just with attendees:

```
    var meetings = _reader.Query()
                .Where(room => room.Id == query.Id)
                .Include(room => room.Meetings)
                    .ThenInclude(meeting => meeting.Meeting)
                .Select(room => new Models.MeetingRoom
                {
                    Id = room.Id,
                    Name = room.Name,
                    Location = room.Location,
                    Meetings = room.Meetings.Where(meeting => meeting.Meeting.StartTime >= query.StartTime && meeting.Meeting.EndTime <= query.EndTime).Select(meeting => new MeetingRoomMeeting
                    {
                        MeetingId = meeting.MeetingId,
                        Meeting = new Models.Meeting
                        {
                            StartTime = meeting.Meeting.StartTime,
                            Attendees = meeting.Meeting.Attendees
                        } 
                    }).ToList()
                })
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

The main difference is that I have to go into the join table "MeetingRoomMeeting" and find the specific meeting and specify I want `Attendees`as well.

This generates a query much like the above:

```
N'SELECT [meeting].[MeetingRoomId], [meeting].[MeetingId], [meeting.Meeting].[StartTime], [meeting.Meeting0].[Id]
FROM [MeetingRoomMeeting] AS [meeting]
INNER JOIN [Meeting] AS [meeting.Meeting] ON [meeting].[MeetingId] = [meeting.Meeting].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Meeting] AS [meeting.Meeting0] ON [meeting].[MeetingId] = [meeting.Meeting0].[Id]
WHERE ([meeting.Meeting].[StartTime] >= @__query_StartTime_1) AND ([meeting.Meeting].[EndTime] <= @__query_EndTime_2)',N'@__query_StartTime_1 datetime2(7),@__query_EndTime_2 datetime2(7)',@__query_StartTime_1='2016-10-02 22:00:00',@__query_EndTime_2='2016-11-03 22:59:59'
```

And then a ton of these:

```
SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[Internal], [a].[MeetingId], [a].[PersonId], [a].[Rating], [a].[WasOrganizer]
FROM [Attendee] AS [a]
```

I'm sure I do something which is a big no-no in terms structuring my LINQ query. I've considered adding a MeetingRoom.Id on an Attendee, to be able to turn the query around with a `MeetingRoom.Id INNER JOIN Attendee.MeetingRoom_Id`

Comment: Try include `meeting.Meeting.Attendees` as well. It seems that your atendees is lazy loaded.

Comment: Didn't seem to work unfortunately. Tried both with .Include(room => room.Meetings).ThenInclude(meeting => meting.Meeting.Attendees) and [..].ThenInclude(meeting => meeting.Meeting).ThenInclude(meeting => meeting.Attendees) - still makes the queries in my profiler.